# Twilio Basic + Global Conferencing in one app?

Tags: twilio, twilio-click-to-call

I have a Rails app successfully creating conferences using Twilio's API at https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/conference  I highly recommend Twilio.

I am looking at the page for Twilio Global Conferencing at https://www.twilio.com/user/account/voice-sms-mms/conferences (this page requires login).

I understand the difference between Basic vs. Global conferences described at that link, but it's not clear to me what happens when I select one.  Three questions:

1. If I select Global Pricing, does that affect pricing for all phone calls happening on all my phone numbers listed at https://www.twilio.com/user/account/phone-numbers/incoming or just when I'm using the  TwilML verb?
2. I will have some conference calls that will have more than 40 participants.  In one Rails app, is there a way to use Global Conferencing for only those large phone calls so that I can use Basic Conferencing for the 90% of calls that have less than 40 participants?

Thank you!

application.rb:

```
config.twilio_auth_token = ENV['TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN']
config.twilio_app_sid = ENV['TWILIO_APP_SID']
```

twilio.rb:

```
if Rails.configuration.twilio_account_sid.present? && Rails.configuration.twilio_auth_token.present?
  TWILIO = Twilio::REST::Client.new(
    Rails.configuration.twilio_account_sid,
    Rails.configuration.twilio_auth_token
  ).account
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio evangelist here.

The Basic vs Global conference setting is scoped to an account or subaccounts, so what you can do is create subaccounts and configure conference the setting on each independently.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thx, @DevinRader is there a way to connect two subaccounts to a Rails app or is it limited to one account per app due to how Rails initializers work?

Comment: You can always define two different Twilio clients within your Rails application if you need to. I'm not sure how you are initialising it at the moment, but if you shared more details I could show you what you could do.

Comment: Hello @philnash I updated the post to show how I'm initializing the Twilio client.  The scenario is that I'm hosting a bunch of events, and some will need to use "global conferences" accept over 40 people.  Thank you for any advice.

Comment: The easiest way to do that would be to save your subaccount details with Global conferencing turned on to two other environment and application variables and create a TWILIO_GLOBAL client using those during the same initialiser. Then you can choose which you'll need at the time of making the call.